# Android Button Border Color

Tags: android, xml, button

I am making Android Button, using following XML.

The output on Preview of Design, shows as below.
[image]

However when I run on Device, Samsung Duos. It shows totally different.
[image]

How can I set border.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#d78d79" />

</shape>
```

I also get an error in XML, but its working fine. Nothing shown when I mouse hover on error.

[image]

Can any one help?

Comment: Show `@drawable/button_border` content

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add `<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />` as an child element in your `shape` element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#d78d79" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Why difference in Design and Device?

Comment: It's `Samsung`... customizing android themes... I don't know. Please check if setting it to transparent will help

Comment: Can u alter XML? As If I use @android:color twice, so receive  error.

Comment: See my answer edit, but if this code would not fix your issue you should set solid android:color attribute to value same as your layout background.

Answer (score 8):

I usually do something like this!

You can do all this in one XML but I will show the long way for you to understand better.

**simple_button.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"/>

    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled"/>
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_enabled"/>

</selector>
```

**button_pressed.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="#20FF5252" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />
    <size
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="35dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#1DE9B6" />
</shape>
```

**button_disabled.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="14dp"
        />
    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/transparent"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="8dp"
        android:color="#1DE9B6"
        />
</shape>
```

**button_enabled.xml**

```
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="2dp"
    />
    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/transparent"
    />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
    />
    <size
        android:width="260dp"
        android:height="50dp"
    />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#1DE9B6"
    />
</shape>
```

**styles.xml**

```
 <style name="Widget.Button.Simple" parent="android:Widget">
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/simple_button</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:textAppearanceMedium</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#1DE9B6</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>

    </style>
```

**Usage**

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_simple"
        style="@style/Widget.Button.Simple"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="Button" />
```

I hope it helps!